# Not able to find sales path setting option in the setup menu

Tags: sales

I am not able to find **sales path setting** option in the setup menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that salesforce has changed title of this setup menu item.

Try locating under Setup > Path > Path Settings

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212199&type=1